# Batch file changes path for startup of all shortcuts

Tags: powershell, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

So what my batch file does currently is it asks for name of new path and what the old one was and then it copies the old files contents and puts them in the new one.

What i want to do after this is change the path of all files that end with .lnk
and change theyr START IN and TARGET from old to new.

I think what would be possible is also to just make the target of new link to the .exe file with same name.

```
@Echo Off
Set /P "oldname= Old name: "
Set /P "newname= New name: "
md "%newname%"
XCopy "%oldname%" "%newname%" /E /I

FOR /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f IN (`dir /b "%newname%\*Shortcut*"`) DO (
SET shortcut=%%f 
mklink /d %shortcut% %shortcut: .lnk=%
)
pause
```

Comment: a) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) for an explanation of why it doesn't work. b) you want to remove `<SPACE>.lnk`? c) use modifiers: `mklink /d "%%f" "%%~nf"` (no variable and so no delayed expansion needed forthat)

Comment: Ahh so thats why my var didnt work as it should - upvote. What if my shortcut looks like this `program.exe - Shortcut.lnk`, how would you then remove the whole " - Shortcut.lnk"

Comment: `set "shortcut=%%~na"` and `echo !shortcut: - Shortcut.lnk=&REM!` - Awkward in terms of programming, but works.